# Cannot implicitly convert int to byte

Tags: c#

I'm having this error, and I can't seem to fix it. It says cannot implicity convert int to byte. Any fixes?

```
bool flag3 = num == 1;
if (flag3)
{
    array[0] = (this.db_bytes[startIndex] & 127);
    result = BitConverter.ToInt64(array, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you haven't clearly shown the types involved, but I'm guessing it's this line that needs to be fixed as follows :

```
array[0] = (byte)(this.db_bytes[startIndex] & 127)
```

as &  will promote it to an int.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

> Those operators are defined for the int, uint, long, and ulong types. When both operands are of other integral types (sbyte, byte, short, ushort, or char), their values are converted to the int type, which is also the result type of an operation. When operands are of different integral types, their values are converted to the closest containing integral type.